# PHP opendir() - how to get the file list of one step UP?

Tags: php, xampp, directory-structure

A simple thing to do. Want to change the XAMPP page view with an addition so that, all the project folders can be viewed on the home page (like the WAMP). I's following [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/dynamic-project-listing-for-xampp) and it's working fine (though the whole thing din't match exactly). I made a link to the `projects.php` page on the left nav area, and on-click I can get all my project folders.

But I want all the projects list on the home page, no further menu click. So I tried, but failed. I tried with [these code](http://pastebin.com/W14xnWCt) (I'm using XAMPP 3.2.1).

But with the code, I can't get it done. I'm confused with two pieces of code there:

```
$handle = opendir(".");
```

and

```
if ( is_dir($file) && ($file != "..") && ($file != ".") ) {
```

As I'm now dealing with new folder structure, I tried using: `$handle = opendir("../");` — but it's always missing the `htdocs` folder.

I even tried simple way like (in `htdocs/xampp/index.php`):

```
<frame name="content" src="start.php" marginwidth=20>
<frame name="content" src="../projects.php" marginwidth=20>
```

But eventually failed.

And also tried:

```
$rp = realpath('../'); //showing: C:\xampp\htdocs
$handle = opendir("$rp"); //but opening the directory C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp
```

Comment: Why did you do this hard code to just change localhost path? Just change the DocumentRoot path at C:\xammp\htdocs\apache\conf\httpd.conf and it will set the patha s your localhost homepage. just chill

Comment: I can also do it by simply overwriting the `htdocs\index.php` with my `porjects.php` code, I know, but I want to keep the present setup and want to append my addition. And I want to learn the `opendir()` thing too. :)

Comment: Haveyou tried 
    $handle = opendir("../../");

Comment: Regardless of using `../` or `../../` it's showing only a single folder `localhost/xampp/img`. But with `../` if I remove the check `is_dir($file) && ` portion, then all the files and folders are visible of `htdocs/`, but I want only the folders... what can I do then?